# Wifi/3g in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-networking

Does the android emulator in eclipse contain 3g?
I would like to know if the emulator contains 3g or not.If it contains,Then by default,will it be enabled?

Comment: good question yes it used 3G

Comment: is there anyway to disable it?

Comment: i think no coz i never try and also not see any option by default it show 3G but y u try to disable

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can connect through 3g / wifi to emulator, Just check there will be 3g signal image in top of emulator, Just connect your pc to 3g internet/wifi it will deflect automatically, If not just restart emulator..